# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'x\x\x\x\bin\debug\project.dll

Tags: c#, nunit

I added a couple of folders to my C# project and now when ever I try to run project from NUnit I always encounter following exception -

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'x\x\x\x\bin\debug\project.dll

Project dll file is not generated and exception details are:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException...
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights,         Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options,               SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
   at NUnit.Core.AssemblyReader.CalcHeaderOffsets()
   at NUnit.Core.AssemblyReader..ctor(String assemblyPath)
   at NUnit.Util.RuntimeFrameworkSelector.SelectRuntimeFramework(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Util.DefaultTestRunnerFactory.GetTargetProcessModel(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Util.DefaultTestRunnerFactory.MakeTestRunner(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Util.TestLoader.LoadTest(String testName)
```

Comment: Is the dll indeed in `x\x\x\x\bin\debug\`? Or is it in another directory?

Comment: Nop it is not there, dll is not generated when I build the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a file path that you typed in?  If so, use Windows explorer to copy/paste the correct path to avoid any typos.

If it is a reference dll that you added through VS, you should delete the reference and add it again to update its path.

As @Oded said, verify that the file exists and that the path is correct.

Comment: When I build the project, dll is not generated and so as the error. Though I am not sure as to why dll is not generated.

Comment: @Tarun:  Let me see if I can understand you better: Do you have multiple projects within a solution?  And is one of them the class library that you are generating?  If so, you can click on "Rebuild All" or you can manually right click the correct project and select "Build."  If you have multiple projects, the project that generates the .dll might be set to build an executable or something else.  That is, check Project->"project name" properties->Application->Output Type.  It should be set to Class library if and only if it should generate a class.

Comment: @Eugenio, I have just one project and its output is set to "Class library", I build the project as you specified but yet I don't see project dll under \bin\debug folder. It used to be there all the while when ever I would build the project. The only change I have made since then is - I created a couple of folders and moved cs files to these folders. And every thing is doomed now :(, I wonder if I should create project again...

Comment: @Tarun:  "Doomed" is a very strong word! :)  Ok.  Let's diagnose this step by step:  1) what is the name of your project.  Is it "project" or is it something else?  2)  When you build your project, do you get any build errors?  3)  When the project is successfully built, are there any output dlls at all?  What is their name?  Do you expect their name to be "project"?  ---- In short, is Visual Studio generating any dll at all?  and if it is not doing so, is it informing you of the problem?

Comment: @Tarun:  You could try starting a new project, but it is best if you find out what is causing the problem.  Have you tried returning the .cs files to their original location?  Perhaps what is happening is that VS cannot find the source files, and consequently, it cannot successfully build your project to generate a dll.  This is important:  Can you verify whether there are any build errors?  You can do this by looking at the status bar on the lower left of the screen after you Rebuild.  Does it say "Build Succeeded" or "Build Failed"?

Comment: It always indicates build success, I was wondering if build should return error when dll is not generated. Though that's not the case here. Now I remember that I just dragged and dropped .cs files to new folders. When I looked at folder locations they were still there and I did svn delete and commit, now when I check out the solution to a different location I yet see the deleted files. I guess I have twisted solution and would start a new project. Since code base is very very small I could do it now. Given the comments you followed up with I am going to mark your answer a right

Comment: @Tarun:  Thanks Tarun :)   I hadn't logged on for a while, but I hope your solution is now working.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this would help you. I came here looking for the same error.
I was using something like this in the test method to read a Json file that I just added to the project.

string currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

It was throwing the same error 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not find file' in debug folder.

I resolved it by changing the settings on the file.
Right click > properties > set Copy to Output Directory to Copy Always.
[Screen shot of the above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/favR0.png)

I am not sure if that is a default setting on files that you add manually.