# NUnit - System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: unit-testing, exception, testing, nunit

Im trying to load a .dll into Nunit which I have never used before(NUnit), when I try open the .dll in Nunit I get the following error. I have no idea whats going wrong , Google doesn't turn up much on this. Any suggestions?

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException...

Server stack trace: 
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, ObjectHandleOnStack retTypes)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes()
   at NUnit.Core.CoreExtensions.InstallAdhocExtensions(Assembly assembly)
   at NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Load(String path)
   at NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Build(String assemblyName, Boolean autoSuites)
   at NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Build(String assemblyName, String testName, Boolean autoSuites)
   at NUnit.Core.TestSuiteBuilder.BuildSingleAssembly(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.TestSuiteBuilder.Build(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.SimpleTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.RemoteTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at NUnit.Core.TestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Util.TestDomain.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Util.RemoteTestAgent.AgentRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext)

Exception rethrown at [1]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at NUnit.Core.TestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Util.ProcessRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Util.TestLoader.LoadTest(String testName)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'x\x\x\x\bin\debug\project.dll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695225/system-io-filenotfoundexception-could-not-find-file-x-x-x-x-bin-debug-project)

Comment: What do you mean by "dll I never used before"? Is it a third party library?

Comment: I was referring to NUnit, yes the other thread is similar but no clear solution was found and I have a .dll in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that there is no development stage assembly in the GloballyAssemblyCache.

In my case, NUnit failed to load `Npgsql.Tests.dll`.

`Npgsql.Tests.dll` links to `Npgsql.dll`. However GAC has another variant of `Npgsql.dll` with same version.

If assembly has fully qualified reference name like `Npgsql, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7`, .NET runtime tries to search assembly from GAC at first, and then search your local folder (Probes for the assembly). We can it check at msdn  [How the Runtime Locates Assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf(v=vs.110).aspx)